# Who are Sahaba and what qualify to be a Sahaba?

Tags: sahaba

What does the word **Sahaba** stand for ?
 
Who qualify to be **Sahaba**?
 
How many people were **Sahaba**?

Comment: Sahaba is arabic for just companion, friend. It doesn't mean anything else.

Comment: A Companion of the Messenger of Allah (SAWS) is one who -- whilst in the state of Imaan (Faith) -- has (at the very least) seen the Messenger (SAWS) or even heard him speak, and then also died on Islam. We typically affix the dua (prayer) *RadiAllahu anhu* (May Allah be pleased with him) or *anha* (with her) after their names, depending upon their gender.

Answer (score 2):

> What does the word Sahaba stand for and Who qualify to be Sahaba?

The word **Sahaba "الصحابة‎"** is derived from صحبة which means to accompany and spend time with.

As a specialized term it means a person who met the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ as a Muslim and died as a Muslim - This is the more widely adopted definition. Ref: [Al-Isabah fi tamyiz al Sahabah](https://shamela.ws/book/9767/124)

Other definitions put additional constraints such as spending a minimum amount of time (e.g. a  year) with the Prophet ﷺ , or fighting a battle alongside him, or narrating a hadith from him, or being of a certain minimum age when he met him.

> How many people were Sahaba?

Nobody knows the total number of Sahaba.

Comment: You should also add to whoever meet that they were muslim

Answer (score 0):

> Who qualify to be Sahaba?

Someone who see each other with Prophet Mohammed (peace be upon him) and became a Muslim, he becomes Sahaba.

Answer (score 0):

> Who are Sahaba and what qualifies to be a Sahaba?

**Sahaba** (Arabic: **الصحابة‎**) refers to the companions of the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) who believed in him, supported him, and followed his teachings during his lifetime. They are considered to be among the most honored and respected figures in Islamic history.

**To be considered a Sahaba,** one had to have met the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), believed in him and his message, and died as a Muslim. The term Sahaba is also applied to the first generation of Muslims who lived during the time of the Prophet and who transmitted his teachings and practices to future generations.

The Sahaba were instrumental in spreading the message of Islam throughout Arabia and beyond, and many of them played important roles in the development of Islamic law, theology, and spirituality. They are revered for their piety, devotion, and service to Islam, and their lives serve as a model for Muslims to follow.

**How many people were Sahaba?**

The exact number of Sahaba is not known, as there were many who met and believed in the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) during his lifetime. However, it is estimated that the number of Sahaba ranges from 100,000 to 200,000. Of these, some of the most famous and influential Sahaba include Abu Bakr, Umar, Uthman, Ali, Aisha, and Khadija. The Sahaba played a critical role in the early development of Islam and their contributions are considered invaluable to the religion.

**Hadiths about sahabah**

There are many hadiths (sayings of the Prophet Muhammad, peace be upon him) that highlight the importance and virtues of the Sahaba. Here are a few examples:

Abu Hurairah reported:

> The Messenger of Allah (peace be upon him) said, "Do not revile my
> Companions! By Him in Whose Hand is my soul, if any one of you spent
> gold equal to Uhud (mountain) in the way of Allah, it would not reach
> the excellence of one of them, nor even half of it." (Sahih
> Al-Bukhari)

Anas reported:

> The Prophet (peace be upon him) said, "The best of my Ummah (nation)
> are my contemporaries (Sahaba), then those who will follow them, and
> then those who will follow the latter. Then there will come after them
> people who will be dishonest and will not be trustworthy, and they
> will bear witness without being asked to do so." (Sahih Al-Bukhari)

Abu Musa reported:

> The Prophet (peace be upon him) said, "The example of my Companions is
> like that of stars in the sky. Whichever star you follow, you will be
> rightly guided." (Sunan At-Tirmidhi)

These hadiths, along with many others, emphasize the high status and honor of the Sahaba and encourage Muslims to respect and follow their example.

Comment: Please clearly distinguish your own words from external quotes by marking them as such!

Comment: edited it, thanks for informing

Answer (score 0):

Companions of the Prophet pbuh, Arabic Ṣaḥābah or Aṣḥāb, in Islam, followers of Muhammad pbuh who had personal contact with him, however slight. In fact, any Muslim who was alive in any part of the Prophet’s lifetime and saw him may be reckoned among the Companions.
The Companions, being eyewitnesses, are the most important sources of Hadith, the record of Prophet Muhammad’s pbuh sayings and activities.

To be considered a Sahaba, one had to have met the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him), believed in him and his message, and died as a Muslim. The term Sahaba is also applied to the first generation of Muslims who lived during the time of the Prophet and who transmitted his teachings and practices to future generations.

Abu Musa reported:

The Prophet (peace be upon him) said, "The example of my Companions is like that of stars in the sky. Whichever star you follow, you will be rightly guided." (Sunan At-Tirmidhi)

These hadiths, along with many others, emphasize the high status and honor of the Sahaba and encourage Muslims to respect and follow their example.

https://www.britannica.com/topic/Companions-of-the-Prophet